# Display latitude and longitude in a UITextView that is a subview of the UIWindow:

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to write a program that displays count, latitude and longitude in a UITextView that is a subview of the UIWindow. I couldn't make it to display the information properly on the simulator screen. Any help is appreciated!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end
@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    int count;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    count++;
    CLLocation *location=locations[0];
    UITextView *textview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 30)];
    textview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    NSString *coun=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count];
    NSString *lat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *lon=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];
   textview.text =(@"%@ %@-%@", coun, lat, lon);
   [self.view addSubview:textview];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope , Following info can help you:

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface yourController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    int count;

}

@end
```

and add this:

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

callback function:

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

store the above values of latitude and longitude in string

```
 NSString *coun=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count];
NSString *lat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newlocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *lon=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newlocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

and then set it to textfield:

```
   textview.text =(@"%@ %@-%@", coun, lat, lon);
```

You also have to add a string for the (in info.plist)

```
    [`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`]
```